# How FastAuth save the private keys

Tags: nearprotocol

I use FastAuth to create a new NEAR account. Then I find that when created, two full access keys are added, when recover, one new full access key is added

1. when I first create account via FastAuth, where does two full access private keys stored?
2. when I recover the account, where does new full access private key stored?